# sql query to fetch one address of many addresses of one person

Tags: sql

two tables : person and addresses ; join condition is addresses.key_value = person.person_id.

there are three addresses.address_type : 'R','M','T'.

fetch person.first_name, addresses.address_1, addresses.zip, addresses.state

if address_type 'T' then fetch the address of 'T' else if 'M' else 'R'.

for each address there is unique address_id in addresses table.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to prioritize the addresses.  Most databases support window/analytic functions, and that provides one mechanism:

```
select p.first_name, a.address_1, a.zip, a.state
from person p join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a.person_id
                                order by (case when a.address_type = 'T' then 1
                                               when a.address_type = 'M' then 2
                                               when a.address_type = 'R' then 3
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from addresses a
     ) a
     on p.person_id = a.person_id and seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want all the addresses of a given type, just switch the `row_number()` to `dense_rank()`:

```
select p.first_name, a.address_1, a.zip, a.state
from person p join
     (select a.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by a.person_id
                                order by (case when a.address_type = 'T' then 1
                                               when a.address_type = 'M' then 2
                                               when a.address_type = 'R' then 3
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from addresses a
     ) a
     on p.person_id = a.person_id and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: if address for all three address types are there, for a person.. tthen address of address type 'T' needs to be fetched. if T is not there, M and R is there..then M has to be fetched. if T and M is not there then address of R should be feetched.

Comment: but if we have more than one address of type T its returning only one..same  with M or R.. plz help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqlserver 2005+, this could be your solution:

```
select * from person p
--cross apply instead of outer apply if you only want people with addresses
outer apply
(select top 1 with ties * from addresses where p.person_id = key_value
order by case address_type when 'T' then 1 when 'M' THEN 2 WHEN 'R' THEN 3 END
) a
```

Comment: if address for all three address types are there, for a person.. tthen address of address type 'T' needs to be fetched. if T is not there, M and R is there..then M has to be fetched. if T and M is not there then address of R should be feetched.

Comment: @user2886453 isn't that exactly what my query does ?